# Linear integer program of modified subset-sum

Tags: algorithms

Can I get help finishing this so I know how to do this if a similar question is asked in the future? I realize I missing constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read this correctly, just introduce an extra variable $z$ and write:
$$
\begin{align}
\max\> & z\\
     & z = \sum_i s_i x_i\\
     & z \le k \\
     & x_i \in \{0,1\}
\end{align}
$$